# Unique Contraint/Index Based On Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, index, constraint

I have a table that has the following column definitions:

```
ID (INT, PK)
Name (VarChar)
Active (Bit)
Bunch_of (Other_columns)
```

**Question:** I want to have a Constraint on `Name/Active` such that we can only have 1 record with a given `Name` that is `Active` (`Active` = 1), but we could have many records that have the same `Name` that are `Inactive` (`Active` = 0). Is this possible?

I've tried the normal Unique constraints, but they limit the dataset to only allow 1 record with a given `Name` to be `Inactive`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a 'default' flag that can only be set on a single row](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/how-to-implement-a-default-flag-that-can-only-be-set-on-a-single-row)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enforce this declaratively in 2005 you can use an indexed view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ActiveNames
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT Name
FROM  dbo.YourTable
WHERE Active = 1

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_ActiveNames ON dbo.ActiveNames(Name)
```

Comment: Geez, how did I not think of this? This is definitely the best answer.

Comment: +1, very concise. Also the comment about UDF reliability is very important. Thanks.

Comment: Luckily, I was able to upgrade to SQL 2008 and use a Filtered Index. However, if that was not an option, this would definitely be the approach I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using CHECK constraint which execute function. Didn't test it completely but it works fine in my initial tests. Here is working eg.

```
CREATE function fn_checkNA(
@name varchar(6) )
 Returns smallint
 as 
  Begin
   Declare @c smallint
    if (select count(1) from dbo.chktest where Name = @name and Active = 1) > 1
     Set @c = 1
    else
     set @c = 0
   Return @c
  End
```

Create table :

```
create table chktest( ID INT primary key,Name VarChar(6) CONSTRAINT chkname CHECK(dbo.fn_checkNA(Name) = 0)
,Active Bit )
```

Now try to run below insert.

```
 insert into chktest values(1,'James', 0)
  insert into chktest values(2,'James',1)
  insert into chktest values(3,'James',0)
  insert into chktest values(4,'James',1)  --- This fails
```

Please test thoroughly before using this method.

NJ

Comment: Using UDFs in check constraints can fail under [snapshot isolation](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/31985/0/page/4) or [multirow updates](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/02/07/using-a-udf-in-a-check-constraint-to-check-validity-of-history-windows-start-end-date-windows.aspx)