# Add constraint to ensure flag column is <= sum of column in other table

Tags: sql-server

I have a column *RSEFlag* that contains a flag value that is the sum of one or more of 1, 2, 4. I have separate table that contains the description of each of those flag values:

```
RSECode RSEDescription
------- --------------
   4    Environment
   1    Reliability
   2    Safety
```

I would like to constrain my *RSEFlag* column so that it is less than or equal to the sum of values from the RSE table.

Is this a worthwhile exercise and what is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a worthwhile exercise and what is the best approach?

IMO this it is not a worthwhile exercise to try and enforce this kind of constraint with DRI because of the concurrency problems alone associated with the UDF and trigger methods of constraining the data - and there are other caveats too as Nick mentions

Of course you can 'enforce' this kind of constraint in a transactional API - see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/writing-a-simple-bank-schema-how-should-i-keep-my-balances-in-sync-with-their-tr/5647#5647) for my answer to a related question for details of what I mean

Answer (score 4):

- You can use a `CHECK` constraint defined against a UDF to enforce this, [but this comes with many caveats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/how-to-force-one-record-to-have-true-value-for-boolean-column-and-all-others-fals/4796#4796).
- You can also define `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers to do this same work.
- In Oracle, you could create a materialized view that joined the two tables together and placed your `RSEFlag` column next to the appropriate sum.  Then you would apply a `CHECK` constraint to enforce that `RSEFlag <= RSECode_SUM`.  [This Ask Tom discussion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:698031000346429496) has an example of how to do this. (Search for `alter table dept_tot_mvw add constraint` and note that `dept_tot_mvw` is a materialized view.)

  Unfortunately, you cannot use this approach since constraints are not allowed on indexed views in SQL Server.

Comment: The materialized view solution for Oracle has it's own problems in my opinion - because the MV only refreshes when you `commit`.